# Transition to a view in table with dynamic cells

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview, storyboard

I create tableview and I fill the table dynamic data.

How to create transition between cell and another view.

Сells are filled with the names of files in the folder documents.

I use storyboard.

App for iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make transition from cell to another view using following code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 anotherView *obj    =[[anotherView alloc]initWithNibName:@"anotherView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
[obj release];

}
```

this method is a delegate method of tableview and when you will select any cell ,it will be called and will go to another view

Comment: you can create xib for another view and also another view in general storyboard.it's depend on you.I prefer another xib as i don't have much experience in storyboard.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! But i am use Master-Detail Application template and when i turn to another view I want it to view was on full screen, not only on the right.

Comment: I am not getting you my friend..can you elaborate more clearly??